# Set OnClickListener for child layout

Tags: android, layout, onclicklistener

How to set onClickListener for child layout...every child must open some new activity. I need to set every child clickable to open new activity. Where I need to put a code....I am new
This is my adapter:

```
public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents, ArrayList<Object> childern)
{
    this.parentItems = parents;
    this.childtems = childern;
}

public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity)
{
    this.inflater = inflater;
    this.activity = activity;
}

// method getChildView is called automatically for each child view.
//  Implement this method as per your requirement
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    child = (ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition);

    TextView textView = null;
    ImageView img = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, null);
    }

    // get the textView reference and set the value
    textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChild);
    textView.setText(child.get(childPosition));
    img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childImage);


        if (childPosition == 0 && groupPosition==0) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika1);
        }
        if (childPosition == 1 && groupPosition==0) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika2);
        }
        if (childPosition == 2 && groupPosition==0) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika1);
        }
        if (childPosition == 3 && groupPosition==0) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika2);
        }
        if (childPosition == 4 && groupPosition==0) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika1);
        }
        if (childPosition == 5 && groupPosition==0) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika2);
        }
        if (childPosition == 6 && groupPosition==0) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika1);
        }
        if (childPosition == 7 && groupPosition==0) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika2);
        }
        if (childPosition == 8 && groupPosition==0) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika1);
        }
        if (childPosition == 0 && groupPosition==1) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika2);
        }
        if (childPosition == 1 && groupPosition==1) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika1);
        }
        if (childPosition == 2 && groupPosition==1) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika2);
        }
        if (childPosition == 3 && groupPosition==1) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika1);
        }
        if (childPosition == 0 && groupPosition==2) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika2);
        }
        if (childPosition == 1 && groupPosition==2) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika1);
        }
        if (childPosition == 2 && groupPosition==2 ) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika2);
        }
        if (childPosition == 3 && groupPosition==2) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika1);
        }
        if (childPosition == 0 && groupPosition==3) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika2);
        }
        if (childPosition == 1 && groupPosition==3) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika1);
        }
        if (childPosition == 2 && groupPosition==3) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika2);
        }
        if (childPosition == 3 && groupPosition==3) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika1);
        }

    // set the ClickListener to handle the click event on child item
   convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, child.get(childPosition),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

// method getGroupView is called automatically for each parent item
// Implement this method as per your requirement
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_view, null);
    }

    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));
    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: post xml code of your code

Answer (score 0):

```
mExpandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(final ExpandableListView parent, final View v, final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, final long id) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to set the background and the click listener instead of if conditions:

```
        Intent intent  = null;
         switch (groupPosition){
                case 0:
                    switch (childPosition){
                        case 0:
                            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika1);
                            intent  = new Intent(activity, Activity1.class);
                            break;
                        ....
                    }
                    break;       
                case 1:
                    switch (childPosition){
                        case 0:
                            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.slika2);
                            intent  = new Intent(activity, Activity2.class);
                            break;
                        ....
                    }
                    break;
            }
         convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {    
                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                 }
          });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know how to post a code....I am new here :-(...e-mail? viber? I write like you said but nothing